# Отправка данных формы

Tags: php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "libmail.php";
$m= new Mail; // начинаем
$m->From( "мыло отправителя" ); // от кого отправляется почта
$m->To( "мыло получателя" ); // кому адресованно
$m->Subject( "" );
$m->Body( "" );    
$m->Cc( "мыло получателя"); // копия письма отправится по этому адресу
$m->Bcc( "мыло получателя"); // скрытая копия отправится по этому адресу
$m->Priority(3) ;    // приоритет письма
//$m->Attach( "3123432.gif","", "image/gif" ) ;
$m->smtp_on( "smtp.mail.ru", "мыло отправителя", "пароль от мыла отправителя" ) ; // если указана эта команда, отправка пойдет через SMTP
$m->Send();    // а теперь пошла отправка
$m->Receipt(); 
echo "Показывает исходный текст письма:<br><pre>", $m->Get(), "</pre>";
?>

<form action="1.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="m">eMail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="m" id="m" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="m">Тема письма:</label>
    <input type="text" name="m" id="m" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="m">Текст письма:</label>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="m" id="m"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт без формы работает, даже на эту форму не обращает внимание, работает как прежде. Только нужно, чтобы через форму заполнялось и отправлялось, емеил, текст были написаны уже через форму, а не через скрипт. Как это можно организовать с такой или другой формой к этому php скрипту? Менять переменные в скрипте нельзя, не будет работать!

Comment: это все в файле 1.php лежит?

Comment: да файл 1.php все в нем, это и есть 1.php

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" name="m" id="m" size="30" />
```

изменяй на разные имена и ID

```
$m= new Mail; // начинаем
$m->From( "мыло отправителя" ); // от кого отправляется почта
$m->To( "мыло получателя" ); // кому адресованно
$m->Subject( "" );
$m->Body( "" );    
$m->Cc( "мыло получателя"); // копия письма отправится по этому адресу
$m->Bcc( "мыло получателя"); // скрытая копия отправится по этому адресу
```

Где тут переменные которые ты получаешь из POST?

Comment: я же говорил если зменить переменные скрипт не заработает!

Comment: покажи как ты их вставляешь туда!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас ошибка в отправке формы. Отправляется в файл 1.php, а обработка в этом же файле.
2. У вас ошибка в `input`, в трёх тегах одинаковые атрибуты `name="m"` и `id="m"`, их необходимо заменить на произвольные не повторяющиеся.
3. Передача аргументов должна производиться из полей формы `$m->To($_POST['email'])`;